How to use AsyncState class of pytransitions Asyncio extension explicitly?
I'm pretty new to Python, asyncio and pytransitions, so I apologize if I'm asking stupid questions.
I'm familiar with GoF's state design pattern and I'm wondering how I can implement this pattern with AsyncMachine and AsyncState.  The goal is a standardized interface for my class MyBaseAsyncState(AsyncState).
In the first step I want to start from example "Very asynchronous dancing"  and try to use the class AsyncState explicitly.
I changed the original:
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
import asyncio

class Dancer:
    
    states = ['start', 'left_food_left', 'left', 'right_food_right']
    
    def __init__(self, name, beat):
        self.my_name = name
        self.my_beat = beat
        self.moves_done = 0
        
    async def on_enter_start(self):
        self.moves_done += 1
        
    async def wait(self):
        print(f'{self.my_name} stepped {self.state}')
        await asyncio.sleep(self.my_beat)

    async def dance(self):
        while self.moves_done < 5:
            await self.step()
        
dancer1 = Dancer('Tick', 1)
dancer2 = Dancer('Tock', 1.1)

m = AsyncMachine(model=[dancer1, dancer2], states=Dancer.states, initial='start', after_state_change='wait')
m.add_ordered_transitions(trigger='step')

# it starts okay but becomes quite a mess
_ = await asyncio.gather(dancer1.dance(), dancer2.dance()) 


to this:
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine, AsyncState, AsyncEvent
import asyncio

class StartState(AsyncState):
    def __init__(self, name, on_enter=None, on_exit = None, ignore_invalid_trigger = True, final = False) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, on_enter, on_exit, ignore_invalid_triggers, final)
        self.add_callback('enter', self.on_enter)

    async def on_enter(self, eventdata: AsyncEvent):
        print("On_enter start state")
        eventdata.model.moves_done += 1

class Dancer:
    
    states = [StartState(name='start'), 'left_food_left', 'left', 'right_food_right']
    
    def __init__(self, name, beat):
        self.my_name = name
        self.my_beat = beat
        self.moves_done = 0
        
    # async def on_enter_start(self):
    #     self.moves_done += 1
        
    async def wait(self):
        print(f'{self.my_name} stepped {self.state}')
        await asyncio.sleep(self.my_beat)

    async def dance(self):
        while self.moves_done < 10:
            await self.step()
        
dancer1 = Dancer('Tick', 1)

m = AsyncMachine(model=[dancer1], states=Dancer.states, initial='start', after_state_change='wait')
m.add_ordered_transitions(trigger='step')
 
await asyncio.gather(dancer1.dance())

I would have expected StartState:on_enter() to be called automatically. Because that doesn't happen, I'm trying to add it explicitly in __init__. But I get the typeerror: 'list' object is not callable
What is my misstake?

There is three small things that need to be adjusted.
First, on_enter and on_exit are 'reserved' in (Async)States. They are considered dynamic methods and get a special treatment. So, when you change async def on_enter to (for instance) on_enter_state the list error should go away.
Second, if you want 'ordinary' callbacks to receive AsyncEventData you need to pass send_event=True to the machine constructor (as mentioned in the Callbacks section of the documentation). This will, however, require all callbacks to have an appropriate signature (as of transitions 0.9.2). So you need to change async def wait(self) to async def wait(self, event_data: AsyncEventData).
Third, a machine passes an instance of type (Async)EventData to the callback and not the (Async)Event itself.
Your code looks somewhat like this with the aforementioned changes:
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine, AsyncState, AsyncEventData
import asyncio


class StartState(AsyncState):
    def __init__(self, name, on_enter=None, on_exit=None, ignore_invalid_trigger=True, final=False) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, on_enter, on_exit, ignore_invalid_trigger, final)
        self.add_callback('enter', self.on_enter_state)

    async def on_enter_state(self, eventdata: AsyncEventData):
        print("On_enter start state")
        eventdata.model.moves_done += 1


class Dancer:
    states = [StartState(name='start'), 'left_food_left', 'left', 'right_food_right']

    def __init__(self, name, beat):
        self.my_name = name
        self.my_beat = beat
        self.moves_done = 0

    # async def on_enter_start(self):
    #     self.moves_done += 1

    async def wait(self, event_data: AsyncEventData):
        print(f'{self.my_name} stepped {self.state}')
        await asyncio.sleep(self.my_beat)

    async def dance(self):
        while self.moves_done < 10:
            await self.step()


dancer1 = Dancer('Tick', 1)

m = AsyncMachine(model=[dancer1], states=Dancer.states, initial='start', after_state_change='wait', send_event=True)
m.add_ordered_transitions(trigger='step')

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(dancer1.dance())

asyncio.run(main())


thank you very much for these clear explanations and corrections!   I figured out the first point myself, but then had a lot of headaches about how to send the event.

I have a general question: it looks to me that pytransitions are usually not used to build state machines in an object orientated way? I mean in the way class stateA.do() ... StateN.do(). Instead, a method is defined in the machine for each behaviour. Do I understand this correctly?

@AlexK: I'd say that transitions is mainly used to build state machines object-oriented. The uncommon trait is that transitions' design separates the stateful object and custom behaviour (model) from the 'rulebook' (machine). This way, one machine can handle multiple models in different states and model-specific callbacks. If you have further questions, don't hesitate asking them here or start a discussion in the project's repo.

Thank you @aleneum for this hint!  That unties the knot in my head. I was wondering why class Dancer, for example, doesn't inherit directly from the AnsyncMachine. Now it makes sense.

A note for people who, like me, come from State Pattern: State Pattern is class-oriented. Transitions is object-oriented. One has to rethink.
